# Mongo Returns data with \n

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mean-stack

I am using a **form builde**r(https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder). I have been able to store the **generated JSON data**(note that i am not sure if the data produced is in JSON form I am just storing it in a JS var) into my MongoDB. Here is where the data is coming from:

```
document.getElementById('getJSON').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var ans = formBuilder.actions.getData('json', true);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: ans,
        url: "/j",
        success: function(){
            console.log('success');
        }
    });

    document.forms["myForm"].submit();
});
```

It is generated here and sent as an AJAX call to the **node server**. The server then does the follows:

```
mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    db.collection('clauses').insertOne(req.session.fdata, function (err, result) {

        console.log('New Clause Added');
        db.close();

    });
});
```

It appears like so in the command prompt
[the standard JSON format in which data appears in MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMDvd.png)

However when i fetch this data it comes as such:

```
 [ { _id: 596de520ef77eb2614cd1e47,
'[\n\t{\n\t\t"type": "number",\n\t\t"label": "Number",\n\t\t"description": 
 "total number",\n\t\t"placeholder": "0",\n\t\t"className": "form-
 control",\n\t\t"name": "number-1500374279764"\n\t}\n]': '' },
{ _id: 596de520ef77eb2614cd1e48 } ]
```

Am I passing the data in the wrong form? Or is the inserted data not in JSON  in the first place? I am new to working with JSON and NOSQL databases.

Comment: Maybe change ... insertOne(req.session.fdata ... to insertOne(JSON.parse(req.session.fdata) ... in the server code.

Comment: @L4reds thanks for the suggestion, but that threw a **TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value** error

Comment: Seems like req.session.fdata is an array of object. so do: 
insertOne(req.session.fdata[0], function(err,data....  and also, delete your previously stored data from the db.

Comment: @L4reds that seems to have solved the previous error but now it is unable to read _id component of the data that it is inserting. Will try to solve that.Thanks! (PS: if any idea on how to solve the _id please let me know)

Comment: check and share the format of inserted data on mongodb itself, want to find issue on insert or fetch

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by putting my data through JSON.stringify(JSON.parse()) before it went to the back end. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Also i did not mention the content type when I made the ajax call, that was key to solving this